# Beatifulsoup find_all when a tag is not inside another tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
html = """
<html>
   <h2>Top Single Name</h2>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <p>hello</p>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <div>
      <div>
         <h2>Price Return</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
"""
```

When I Use below code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all(['p', 'li', 'dl', 'tr', 'div', re.compile("^h[1-6]$")])
```

I am getting output as

```
[<h2>Top Single Name</h2>,
 <tr><p>hello</p></tr>,
 <p>hello</p>,
 <div>
 <div>
 <h2>Price Return</h2>
 </div>
 </div>,
 <div>
 <h2>Price Return</h2>
 </div>,
 <h2>Price Return</h2>]
```

But what I need is below only three elements

```
[<h2>Top Single Name</h2>,
<tr><p>hello</p></tr>,
<div>
 <div>
 <h2>Price Return</h2>
 </div>
 </div>
]
```

Basically I don't want to extract a specific tag if it is inside another tag, is there any way i can have some mapping like below and use in the code don't extract when the key is inside value

```
{'re.compile("^h[1-6]$")': 'div', 'div':'div', 'p': 'tr'}
```

Comment: Don't the second and third elements in the expected output have more than one tag? The output should include `<p>hello</p>` and `<h2>Price Return</h2>`  IIUC?

Comment: I don't want to extract ```<p>hello</p>``` as it is inside <tr> tag, similarly for ```<h2>Price Return</h2>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I don't want to extract a specific tag if it is inside another tag

I think the simplest way might be to use `find_all` just as you are now, and then filter out the nested tags by checking if they have ancestors/parents in the list

```py
sel = soup.find_all(['p', 'li', 'dl', 'tr', 'div', re.compile("^h[1-6]$")])
sel = [s for s in sel if not [p for p in sel if p in s.parents]]
```

-- same results as getting tags if their tagName is in a list as long as if none of their parents have one of the listed names:

```py
selTags = ['p', 'li', 'dl', 'tr', 'div'] + [f'h{i}' for i in range(1,7)]
sel = soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name in selTags and not t.find_parent(selTags))
```

---

but if you want to filter by a map

> is there any way i can have some mapping like below and use in the code don't extract when the key is inside value

you could use

```py
parentMap = {'div':'div', 'p': 'tr'}
for i in range(1,7): parentMap[f'h{i}'] = 'div'
# parentMap = {'div': 'div', 'p': 'tr', 'h1': 'div', 'h2': 'div', 'h3': 'div', 'h4': 'div', 'h5': 'div', 'h6': 'div'}

sel = soup.find_all(
    lambda t: t.name in 
    ['p', 'li', 'dl', 'tr', 'div']+[f'h{i}' for i in range(1,7)]
    and not (
        t.name in parentMap and 
        t.find_parent(parentMap[t.name]) is not None
    )
)
```

---

---

In *this* case, you should get the same results either way, but if your html contained

```html
<p><tr>I am a row in a paragraph</tr></p>
```

then the first methods will return only the outer `<p>` tag whereas the last method will return both the `<p>` tag and the inner `<tr>` tag [unless you add `'tr': 'p'` to `parentMap`].